# RegEx - Pattern to find all lowercase words

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a Regex pattern that should find any lowercase word in a sentence. This includes in the middle of the sentence. An example sentence would be...

> Rob Alsod is normal

And it would find 'is' and 'normal' as they both do not begin with a capital letter. I have tried playing around on Regex Tester, but I can't find something that will work.

I am using Python 3.3.2, and here are some things I have tried so far:

```
\s[^A-Z][a-z]*

[A-Z][a-z]*
```

I do not have the greatest knowledge on Regex.

Thank you.

Rob.

Comment: Firstly -- "Regex pattern" is not a specific thing. Different languages and tools have different regex engines that behave differently. You'll need to specify which one you're using. Secondly -- it's not enough to say "I can't find something that will work", you need to tell us what you've already tried, and what was wrong with it.

Answer (score 6):

This regex with word boundaries should work for you:

```
/\b[a-z]+\b/
```

However you do need to provide more info like which language/tool you're using for your coding.

Comment: This doesn't deserve an upvote since it's incomplete, it won't match `éternel`.

Comment: @HamZa: With due regards to your comment, answer can be complete only when question is complete.

Comment: That's why you should close vote it instead of answering it. Especially since the OP didn't show any efforts. There are interesting [meta discussions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188408/why-arent-these-give-me-teh-regexz-questions-closed) about this phenomena in the regex tag.

Comment: Thanks for that link, I will go through the discussion thread.

Comment: Thanks for the friendly encouragement. I added some stuff, now.

Comment: @RobAlsod: I believe above answer should work for you. Do you have non English text as well?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do?

```
import re

re.findall(r'\b[^A-Z\s\d]+\b', u'Rob Alsod is normal (éternel)', re.UNICODE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
(?<= )+[a-z]+\b
```